# Docusign API: how to handle incomplete contracts with embedded signing?

Tags: docusignapi

I have embedded signing within my app but I am not sure how to handle half completed contracts.

I have looked at https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/embeddedSigning.js which does not handle this case.

The problem:

The user goes onto my website and clicks the sign button which opens the DocUSign contract view. They sign two out of three places and then leave.

When the user comes back to my website the code here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/embeddedSigning.js would create a new envelope rather than pick off from the unfinished one earlier.

I would have expected the below

1. get user id from URL
2. search backend for user by id
3. Search DocUSign for incomplete contract
4. show contract view

if not incomplete contract

1. get user id from URL
2. search backend for user by id
3. Create envelope
4. show contract view

What is the expected flow from DocUSign? How should I handle my use case above with the API?

Answer (score 0):

The code example you linked here shows:

1. Creating a new envelope
2. Embedded Signing.

What you want is to use Step 2 above with an existing envelope.

You just need to find the envelopeId for the envelope that you want (the partially signed on) and then do step 2 only.

Step 2 is in this code:

```
function makeRecipientViewRequest(args)
```

The args parameter include

```
  viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
  viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
  viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;
```

So you need to pass these things as well as the `envelopeId`